# Consistency with calculating the Solar Azimuth Angle

Tags: astronomy, geometry

I am struggling to find consistency regarding the calculation of the Solar Azimuth Angle.

The equations across multiple publications have similar terms, but differ significantly. These differences can be seen by comparing their [output](http://tpcg.io/ATL1PE).

Furthermore, I have compared the results of these algorithms to output from several reputable sources. Given my inputs,

- [NOAA](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/calcdetails.html) reports the Solar Azimuth Angle (degrees) as 185.7925368
- [SunCalc](https://www.suncalc.org/#/50,3,7/2019.06.16/14:00/1/3) reports the Solar Azimuth Angle (degrees) as 185.79°

As these agree, I am assuming this is the correct answer. The Algorithm built into the NOAA spreadsheet differs from all the below algorithms as it adds 180 to the final result.

Why are there so many difference in the calculation of the Solar Azimuth Angle, and which one should I be using?

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_azimuth_angle):

[image]

[ScienceDirect states](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/solar-azimuth-angle):

[image]

[pveducation states](https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/azimuth-angle):

[image]

[SolarGeo States](http://mypages.iit.edu/~maslanka/SolarGeo.pdf):

[image]